# Como duplicar información entre 2 columnas MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8.2, aplicación-escritorio, netbeans-8.1

Cómo tengo que hacer para que 2 filas de diferentes columnas dentro de la misma base de datos en MySQL se dupliquen? Eso es posible? Y que se repliquen constantemente. Es decir que cada vez que la aplicación escriba en la fila principal de la base de datos se duplique a otra fila de diferente columna.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: para que querrias desnormalizar tu base de datos? Osea hay veces que es una opcion pero me dio curiosidad

Comment: Simplemente porque ya estaba organizada y me pidieron que agregue mas columnas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es posible, podrias utilizar un disparador. (trigger)

Son muy utiles para este tipo de cuestiones.

Funcionan cada vez que se ejecuta una accion se desencadene otro evento, en tu caso que escriba en otra columna.

> https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/triggers_mysql

Comment: Anduvo! Muchas gracias